# Do stalks see epimorphism of stacks?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, topos-theory, infinity-topos-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a site and $f:\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{G}$ a morphism of $2$-sheaves. According to  https://mathoverflow.net/q/307366, this is an epimorphism if and only if it is *almost surjective*, that is to say if for all $U$, and any $g\in G(U)$, there exists an open cover $\{U_i\to U\}$ such that there exists $x_i\in F(U_i)$ such that $f(x_i)\cong g\rvert_{U_i}$. If we assume that our $2$-topos has enough points,  can we check this on stalks, that is to say on the pullback of $f$ to all points of our $2$-topos?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by an "$n$-sheaf"?  In the most common higher-categorical formulation, an $n$-sheaf lives in a weak $(n+1)$-category, where it doesn't even make sense to ask about whether something is an isomorphism (versus an equivalence).

Comment: Oh, right, how embarassing! Apologies, I'll change the question accordingly, since I'm still curious about the essential surjectivity.

Comment: A conservative functor reflects anything (not really – but I don't want to be precise here) it preserves. The inverse image functor of a geometric morphism preserves finite limits and (possibly infinite) colimits, so in particular it preserves images, and hence reflects the property of being essentially surjective. But the functor $F \mapsto F (U)$  is not usually the inverse image functor of a geometric morphism. You seem to be confusing "sections" vs "stalks".

Comment: To put that differently, if each $\phi_i(f)$ is essentially surjective, then $f$ is *internally* essentially surjective, i.e. effective-epimorphic.  But that doesn't imply that it is sectionwise essentially surjective.  That fails already for 1-sheaves: a map of sheaves of sets can be epimorphic without being sectionwise surjective.

Comment: I'm sorry for my confusion, but for 1-sheaves, surjections on the stalks implies that the image sheaf surjects section-wise. So why does this make it clear that this fails for "higher" sheaves?

Comment: No, it doesn't imply that even for 1-sheaves.  Consider a topological space $X$ that is the union of two opens $U\cup V$.  Then if $y$ denotes the Yoneda embedding, the map of sheaves $yU + yV \to yX = 1$ is surjective stalkwise, but not on sections: $yX$ has a section over the whole space, but $yU + yV$ doesn't.

Comment: @MikeShulman, but I'm not claiming anything about section-wise surjections, aren't I? For $1$-sheaves, if the morphism is surjective on stalks, then the morphism of sheaves is an epimorphism, which isn't beeing section-wise surjective, I'm aware of that

Comment: Oh, I missed that your previous comment was about the *image* sheaf surjecting section-wise, unlike the original question.  That's true for 1-sheaves and also higher sheaves.  In fact, since the image is a subsheaf, it surjects on stalks iff it surjects sectionwise iff it is an isomorphism.

Comment: @MikeShulman Would you happen to have a reference about this? Also, if you just want to write it quickly into an answer so that this doesn't linger in the open questions part?

Comment: I'm always wary of posting an answer to a question that keeps changing.  Is this your final question?  (-:

Comment: Also, the term "epimorphism" for this notion is arguably inappropriate.  In particular, it is not the same as a "monomorphism" in the opposite category.

Comment: @MikeShulman I honestly just changed the question to make it clearer what I was really asking, it seemed inappropriate to ask a separate question which to my mind was basically the same, but apologies if that was wrong. I will not change this question anymore.

Comment: I'm not necessarily saying you were wrong to change the question.  This version doesn't look to me like the same question you started with, since it says nothing about surjectivity on sections, but I can appreciate that this is probably the question you meant to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition (e.g. Remark 6.5.4.7 of *Higher topos theory*), an $n$-topos $\mathcal{E}$ has enough points if for every morphism $f:X\to Y$ in $\mathcal{E}$, whenever $p^*(f)$ is an equivalence for all points $p:\mathcal{S}_n \to \mathcal{E}$ (where $\mathcal{S}_n$ is the $n$-topos of $(n-1)$-groupoids), then $f$ is already an equivalence.

What you call an "epimorphism" or "almost surjective" is perhaps better called an [effective epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/effective+epimorphisms+in+an+%28%E2%88%9E%2C1%29-category), since it is a faithful generalization of that concept from 1-categories, whereas it is not really a faithful generalization of the concept of epimorphism (e.g. it is not the same as a monomorphism in the opposite $n$-category).  By Prop. 7.2.1.14 of *Higher topos theory*, a morphism in an $n$-topos is an effective epimorphism precisely when its truncation to a morphism of 1-sheaves is an (effective) epimorphism in the corresponding 1-topos; this shows that the effective epimorphisms agree with your concrete description.

Now the effective epimorphisms in an $n$-topos are the left class of a [factorization system](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28n-connected%2C+n-truncated%29+factorization+system) whose right class are the monomorphisms.  Thus, a morphism is an effective epimorphism precisely if the monomorphism half of this factorization is an equivalence.  It follows that being an effective epimorphism is reflected by any conservative family of functors, such as the family of points of an $n$-topos with enough points.